# curator reindex action - dynamic index name

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, logstash-configuration, elasticsearch-curator

we have house keeping scripts to run everyday at night to Reindex from daily indices into monthly indices and delete daily indices

```
actions:
  1:
    description: "Reindex application-YYYY.MM.dd into application-YYYY.MM"
    action: reindex
    options:
      disable_action: False
      wait_interval: 9
      max_wait: -1
      request_body:
        source:
          index: REINDEX_SELECTION
        dest:
          index: application-2018.10 #change this
    filters:
    - filtertype: pattern
      kind: prefix
      value: application-
    - filtertype: age
      source: name
      direction: older
      timestring: '%Y.%m.%d'
      unit: days
      unit_count: 1
  2:
    action: delete_indices
    description: >-
      Delete application-%Y.%m.%d indices older than 1 day
    options:
      ignore_empty_list: True
      disable_action: False
    filters:
    - filtertype: pattern
      kind: regex
      value: '^application-\d{4}\.\d{2}.\d{2}'
    - filtertype: age
      source: name
      direction: older
      timestring: '%Y.%m.%d'
      unit: days
      unit_count: 1
```

How do we make monthly index name dynamically? i want to make something like  this application-%Y.%m  instead of hard coding year and month application-2018.10

when i use application-%Y.%m like below- its not working.

```
  request_body:
    source:
      index: REINDEX_SELECTION
    dest:
      index: application-%Y.%m
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use [date math](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.5/option_name.html#_date_math_2) in that expression.  A valid example for you might be:

```
dest:
  index: <application-{now/M{YYYY.MM}}>
```

The bigger problem is, perhaps, “How do you ensure that the last day of the month doesn’t end up in the next month’s index?”  This approach would absolutely result in this outcome.  If you don’t care, then that’s fine. We can talk about potential solutions to that if you like.

Comment: Yes. Thats true.you are right.could you please help me to come out of this issue. I want to run the curator cronjob to everyday at night to Reindex from daily indices into monthly indices and delete daily indices

Answer (score 1):

This may now longer be useful, but I found this question whilst looking for the answer to the same problem, and here's how I fixed it (with help from untergeek's initial answer):

```
actions:
  1:
    action: create_index
    description: "Create index: This is a monthly task"
    options:
      name: '<security-{now/d-1d{YYYY.MM}}>'
      continue_if_exception: True
  2:
    action: reindex
    description: "Reindex daily into monthly"
    options:
      wait_interval: 1
      max_wait: -1
      request_body:
        source:
          index: '<security-{now/d-1d{YYYY.MM.dd}}>'
          query:
            term:
              user: kimchy
        dest:
          index: '<security-{now/d-1d{YYYY.MM}}>'
    filters:
    - filtertype: none
  3:
    action: delete_indices
    description: "Delete yesterday's daily index"
    options:
      ignore_empty_list: True
    filters:
    - filtertype: pattern
      kind: regex
      value: '^security-\d{4}\.\d{2}.\d{2}'
    - filtertype: age
      source: name
      direction: older
      timestring: '%Y.%m.%d'
      unit: days
      unit_count: 1
    - filtertype: age
      source: name
      direction: younger
      timestring: '%Y.%m.%d'
      unit: days
      unit_count: 2
```

I'm also doing a query filter as part of the reindex you can ignore, and also limiting the delete to indexes that are exactly 1 day old, so if a scheduled reindex fails a subsequent curator job won't delete that index.